# How to access/retrieve member variable of PyObject from within python extension

Tags: python, python-extensions

The function PyObject_Call() is used to call a method on a PyObject. But how to get/read a member variable of a PyObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PyObject_GetAttr`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttr) or [`PyObject_GetAttrString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttrString) function.

Also have a look at overall [object protocol documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#object-protocol) for more info